# Как прописать robots.txt для одностраничника на WP?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

Имеется одностраничный сайт на WordPress. Он представляет из себя загруженную и активированную тему, то есть нет зарегестрированных виджетов, сайдбаров и т.п. Единственное что берётся из админки - это название и описание сайта. Все медиафайлы также находятся в папке с темой.

Возникают вопросы - как в этом случае прописать robots.txt? Какие папки запретить/разрешить для индексации? Шаблонные robots.txt из интернета для этой ситуации явно не подходят, поскольку все поголовно предлагают запретить к индексации папку wp-themes, а папку wp-includes, наоборот, разрешить.

Следует ли в данной ситуации переписать данные готовые решения robots.txt запретив индексацию wp-includes и разрешив индексацию wp-themes?
И можно ли просто запретить к индексации всё кроме папки с темой?!

Comment: не вижу проблемы: бот индексирует то, на что есть ссылки. если у вас небольшой одностраничник, то кол-во ссылок, тем более внутренних, стремится к нулю. мне кажется, вообще не стоит так серьезно раздумывать по этому поводу.

Answer (score 2):

Подробный файл robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin          # классика...
Disallow: /?                # все параметры запроса на главной
Disallow: /wp-  # все файлы WP: /wp-json/, /wp-includes, /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: *?s=              # поиск
Disallow: *&s=              # поиск
Disallow: /search           # поиск
Disallow: /author/          # архив автора
Disallow: *?attachment_id=
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: */page/           # все виды пагинации
Allow: */uploads
Allow: /*/*.js              # внутри /wp- (/*/ - для приоритета)
Allow: /*/*.css             # внутри /wp- (/*/ - для приоритета)
Allow: /wp-*.png            # картинки в плагинах, cache папке и т.д.
Allow: /wp-*.jpg            # картинки в плагинах, cache папке и т.д.
Allow: /wp-*.jpeg           # картинки в плагинах, cache папке и т.д.
Allow: /wp-*.gif            # картинки в плагинах, cache папке и т.д.
#Disallow: /wp/             # когда WP установлен в подкаталог wp

Host: www.site.ru

Sitemap: http://site.ru/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://site.ru/sitemap2.xml
```

Как видим, индексация /wp-content/themes/ не запрещена. Что и требуется.

Но обычно все делается гораздо проще. Вот файл robots.txt, генерируемый Yoast SEO (около миллиона установок)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Важно только одно - заблокировать доступ в /wp-admin и разрешить ajax. Все остальное - лирика.